# Why does the collect function stay suspended forever?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to know why the `collect` function in example two keeps waiting indefinitely, unlike example one. Please don't mention `GlobalScope` or `CoroutineScope`. I just want to understand why, in example two, it remains suspended forever compared to example one.

**Example 1**

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        Log.w("ABC", "1")

        runBlocking {
            val flow: Flow<String> = flow {
                for (x in 1..10)
                    this.emit(x)
            }.map {
                "before: $it after: ${it * 2}"
            }

            flow.collect {
                Log.w("ABC", "collect body { $it }")
            }
        }

        Log.w("ABC", "2")
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
2023-12-12 20:25:57.321  9201-9201  ABC                     com.test.app                     W  1
2023-12-12 20:25:57.338  9201-9201  ABC                     com.test.app                     W  collect body { before: 1 after: 2 }
2023-12-12 20:25:57.338  9201-9201  ABC                     com.test.app                     W  collect body { before: 2 after: 4 }
2023-12-12 20:25:57.338  9201-9201  ABC                     com.test.app                     W  collect body { before: 3 after: 6 }
2023-12-12 20:25:57.339  9201-9201  ABC                     com.test.app                     W  collect body { before: 4 after: 8 }
2023-12-12 20:25:57.339  9201-9201  ABC                     com.test.app                     W  collect body { before: 5 after: 10 }
2023-12-12 20:25:57.339  9201-9201  ABC                     com.test.app                     W  collect body { before: 6 after: 12 }
2023-12-12 20:25:57.339  9201-9201  ABC                     com.test.app                     W  collect body { before: 7 after: 14 }
2023-12-12 20:25:57.339  9201-9201  ABC                     com.test.app                     W  collect body { before: 8 after: 16 }
2023-12-12 20:25:57.339  9201-9201  ABC                     com.test.app                     W  collect body { before: 9 after: 18 }
2023-12-12 20:25:57.339  9201-9201  ABC                     com.test.app                     W  collect body { before: 10 after: 20 }
2023-12-12 20:25:57.341  9201-9201  ABC                     com.test.app                     W  2
```

**Example 2**

```
val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "settings")

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        val EXAMPLE_COUNTER = stringPreferencesKey("example_counter")

        Log.w("ABC", "1")

        runBlocking {
            this@LoginActivity.dataStore.data
                .map { preferences ->
                    preferences[EXAMPLE_COUNTER] ?: 497350
                }
                .collect {
                    Log.w("ABC", "collect body { $it }")
                }
        }

        Log.w("ABC", "2")
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
2023-12-12 20:33:23.535 10181-10181 ABC                     com.test.app                     W  1
2023-12-12 20:33:23.589 10181-10181 ABC                     com.test.app                     W  collect body { 497350 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike other reactive frameworks (like rxjava) `Flow`s are pretty loose when it comes to types (both finite and infinite flows are of type `Flow`) and you have to keep it in check yourself through naming or documentation.

There's only a little safety for `SharedFlow` (`collect`-ing it returns `Nothing` instead of `Unit`) but even such safeguard is lost as soon as it's transformed and it becomes a `Flow`.

As for your question:

1. you create flow using `flow(block)` builder. As soon as `block` body is executed the flow finishes and `collect` returns.
2. you obtain flow from datastore, then transform it (with `map`). However datastore flow is infinite so your collect will never return. It will suspend and keep collecting preference changes until cancelled.

If you don't want that you need to change how you collect the flow. Either apply an operator that can terminate it (like `take(1)`) or use `first()` operator instead of `collect` to suspend and return data once (this is also mentioned in datastore documentation).

Comment: `this is also mentioned in datastore documentation` Could you share where is that mentioned in [this document](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore)?

Comment: @TahaSami the section "use datastore in synchronous code" which contains a sample with `runBlocking`.

Comment: Do I always have to use the `take()` function with `flow()` in Kotlin? From what I remember in RxJava, the `Flowable` automatically knows when it reaches the last item to pass it downstream.

Comment: No, as your first sample shows some flows are finite and they will end normally. However some flows are infinite and will be collected until cancelled. Only if you don't want that behavior you can apply operators like take, takeWhile, etc. that will terminate the collection when conditions are met.